# ExtJS pass all fields on store.sync()

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

In ExtJS 6.5.0, I've created a Store and a editable gridpanel:

```
Ext.define('StateStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.stateStore',
    storeId  : 'StateStore',
    fields: ['Id', 'Name', 'SortIndex'],
    autoLoad : true,

    proxy: {
        type : 'ajax',
        api  : {
            create  : undefined,
            read    : '/kanban/states/read/' + kanbanId,
            update  : '/kanban/states/update/' + kanbanId,
            destroy : undefined
        },
        writer : {
            type        : 'json',
            allowSingle : false
        }
    }
});


var StateList = Ext.create({
    xtype : 'gridpanel',
    selModel: 'cellmodel',
    title : 'Manage States',
    store : {
        type: 'stateStore'
    },
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1
    },
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'Id',
            flex: 1
        },{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            flex: 2, 
            editor: {
                field: {
                    type: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            }
        },
        { 
            text: 'SortIndex',
            dataIndex: 'SortIndex',
            flex: 1,
        }
    ],
});
```

When user finish editing and click save, store.sync() function will be called, but it will only pass the modified records and fields to the server. I use `record.dirty=true` to force it pass all records, but the unmodified fields still not passed.

Why I want to pass all the records and fields? Because I'd like to remove the existing records and create new records every time it updates. So I don't need to deal with create/update/delete separately. There will be only a few entries, so performance is not a problem.

One solution is use `Ext.Ajax()` instead of `sync()`, I wonder is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configure your writer with `writeAllFields: true`.

Relevant [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.writer.Writer.html#cfg-writeAllFields).

Comment: yes. setting writeAllFields to true will do. This was set to true by default in the previous versions but for 6.5.0 you've to set it manually.

Comment: `true` to write all fields from the record to the server. If set to false it will only send the fields that were modified. This is only for `fields` within `record`. It will not send `all records` to server.

Comment: @Shahbaz Not sure what you did, but I had to set it manually ever since I started with ExtJS back in v4.2.1.

Comment: @Alexander Looks like we both started with 4.2 but experienced different behavior. you can still check the doc [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Writer-cfg-writeAllFields). It says defaults to: true

Comment: You can use the [critical](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-critical) property to manage single fields instead of the whole model.